# Use cell value as range to hide columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that there is a checkbox the purpose of the checkbox is to hide the name of clients in two adjacent columns. Because the spreadsheet changes from time to time the position of the columns changes thus it is currently P:Q but a year ago it was H:I.

I want to store the 'range' in a cell and reference that from my vba and get that to hide the columns. The checkbox is a simple toggle. I have tried various incarnations without success and my latest effort tells me that I have not se up the range properly. The cel I am using for teh range is F4. The code is currently:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim Visy As Integer
    Dim My_range As String

    'My_range is the range of filled rows stored as a range in cell F4
    'Visy stores the state of the checkbox

    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
            Visy = 1
        Else
            Visy = 0
    End If

    'Stop any use of the spread sheet and set variable initial states
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    My_range = Sheet9.Cells(4, 6).Value

    'Hide the columns
    Range(My_range).Hidden = Visy

    'Sheet9.colums(My_range).Hidden = True

    'Re enable application
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Either dynamically locate the columns by a unique column header text label that moves when the columns move or 'store' the range reference as a defined name (Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager) so the name remains the same but the *Refers to:* will adjust when you insert columns to shift the range.

Answer (score 0):

This is within a **single** sheet:

```
Sub qwerty()
    My_range = Cells(4, 6).Value
    Range(My_range).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I tried this it gave the error 'range or object worksheet failed' and I can confirm that the checkbox is on the same sheet as the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use code in context:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim sRangeName As String

'context!
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TypeNameHere")
sRangeName = wsh.Range("F4")
wsh.Range(sRangeName).EntireColumn.Hidden = CheckBox2.Value

Set wsh = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this and (the worksheet is sheet9 "Client fwd plan 16" but on clicking I am given the error message Compile error method or data member not found. worksheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Client fwd plan 16")

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be [Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) instead of `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Private Sub CheckBox2_Click` should be in a worksheet's code sheet. I believe this is the worksheet identified by the Sheet9 worksheet [.CodeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) property.

A Private Sub in a worksheet codesheet does not have to explicitly reference the [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) worksheet property on any [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) or 
[Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) object unless you want to reference another worksheet's cells. These are bound to the cells on the worksheet whose codesheet you are on regardless of the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx).

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Range(Cells(4, "F").Text).EntireColumn.Hidden = CBool(Me.Value)
End Sub
```

Do not confuse a worksheet's Private Sub behavior with a Private Sub on a module code sheet. A module codesheet should always explicitly reference the parent worksheet (and often the parent workbook) regardless of whether the Sub is Public or Private.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded it helped a lot and put me on the right track. As several of you noted context is important and I was mixing private sub and sub and so had a scope problem when it came to ranges. I also from another source had the suggestion to use a named range rather than read a cell value since the columns were always adjacent.  I have published the code below in case it is of value to anyone in the future.

```
    Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    'Requires ClientNameCol to be set to the range to be hidden
    Dim Visy As Boolean

    'Stop any use of the spread sheet and set variable initial states
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Check if sheet is to be hidden or not

    If Worksheets("Client 16").CheckBox2.Value = True Then
           Visy = True
    Else
           Visy = False
    End If

    'Hide/unhide the columns
     With ThisWorkbook
          .Worksheets("Client 16").Range("ClientNameCol").EntireColumn.Hidden = Visy
     End With


     On Error GoTo 0
     Application.EnableEvents = True


     End Sub
```